# JQUERY: getting the different values from divs with the same class

Tags: jquery

I have cobbled together some code to build an animated percentage bar. Everything works sweet when only one bar is present on a page. I have the following code

```
<div id="progress_bar" class="ui-progress-bar ui-container"> 
<div class="ui-progress" style="width: 60%;"> 
<span class="ui-label" style="display:none;"><b class="value"><span class="client_overall_progress">60</span>%</b></span> 
</div> 
</div>


$(function() {
var overall_progress = $(".client_overall_progress", this) .text();

// Hide the label at start
$('#progress_bar .ui-progress .ui-label').hide();
// Set initial value
$('#progress_bar .ui-progress').css('width', '7%');

// Simulate some progress
$('#progress_bar .ui-progress').animateProgress(overall_progress);
});
```

I would like to be able to place multiple percent bars on my page but i am not sure how to separate all the different values and have each bar render to the correct percent.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing your progress bars with an id of `#progress_bar`. Because elements IDs are suppose to be unique in the DOM, this will cause unexpected behaviors when trying to reach an element by it's ID, like you do on your jQuery selectors.

What you *can* do, is change `#progress_bar` into `.progress_bar`, and instead of defining it with  the id of `progress_bar`, add it as another class to that top DIV.

*(edited into the answer from the comments on it for future references)*

You are calling `.animateProgress` on the whole set of `.client_overall_progress`. The solution is to iterate each `.progress_bar .ui-progress` and animate each element seperately. I've set up a jsfiddle to show you the problem and how to fix it: jsfiddle.net/4xgzq/1

You should just look at the jQuery code and comment out the alert and uncomment the `.animateProgress`.

BTW, I also placed an `alert()` before the `.each()`, to show you what happened with the first `client_overall_progress` selector you used in your script - it grabbed the text of the whole set of them. (That's why the first `alert()` shows you 6060)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I should have noticed that little error myself. what is happening is the values of the .client_overall_progress is that it is concactinating the values together. so if 2 bars are at 60% i get 2 bars at 6060% if you know what i mean

Comment: Yes, I do see what you mean. It's because you are calling `.animateProgress` on the whole set of `.client_overall_progress`.
The solution is to iterate each `.progress_bar .ui-progress` and animate each element seperately.
I've set up a jsfiddle to show you the problem and how to fix it:
http://jsfiddle.net/4xgzq/1/
You should just look at the jQuery code and comment out the alert and uncomment the `.animateProgress`.

Comment: BTW, I also placed an `alert()` before the `.each()`, to show you what happened with the first `client_overall_progress` selector you used in your script - it grabbed the text of the whole set of them. (That's why the first `alert()` shows you 6060)

Comment: absolutely brilliant. i knew it had to be iterated through but i had no idea how to implement it. thank you so much for you quick response